# Rotating javascript array with array.push(array.shift()) and adding result into another array only adds last rotation

Tags: javascript, arrays

This one is a complicated error and I do not know what i've done wrong here.

trying to rotate an array and push the new rotated array to a new array called shifted, and it seems only to push the very last rotation in the for loop.

```
function arrayRotate(arr, reverse = false)
{
    if (reverse)
        arr.unshift(arr.pop());
    else
        arr.push(arr.shift());
    return arr;
}

let teams = ['Afghanistan','Australia','Bangladesh','England','India','Ireland','Netherlands','New Zealand','Pakistan','South Africa', 'Sri Lanka','West Indies','Zimbabwe'];
let maxGames = 8;
let shifted = [];
let rounds = Math.floor(maxGames / 2);
for (let n = 0; n < rounds; n++)
{
    teams = arrayRotate(teams);
    console.log(teams);
    shifted.push(teams);
}
console.log("----");
console.log(shifted);
```

The console output:

```
[
  'Australia',    'Bangladesh',
  'England',      'India',
  'Ireland',      'Netherlands',
  'New Zealand',  'Pakistan',
  'South Africa', 'Sri Lanka',
  'West Indies',  'Zimbabwe',
  'Afghanistan'
]
[
  'Bangladesh',  'England',
  'India',       'Ireland',
  'Netherlands', 'New Zealand',
  'Pakistan',    'South Africa',
  'Sri Lanka',   'West Indies',
  'Zimbabwe',    'Afghanistan',
  'Australia'
]
[
  'England',      'India',
  'Ireland',      'Netherlands',
  'New Zealand',  'Pakistan',
  'South Africa', 'Sri Lanka',
  'West Indies',  'Zimbabwe',
  'Afghanistan',  'Australia',
  'Bangladesh'
]
[
  'India',       'Ireland',
  'Netherlands', 'New Zealand',
  'Pakistan',    'South Africa',
  'Sri Lanka',   'West Indies',
  'Zimbabwe',    'Afghanistan',
  'Australia',   'Bangladesh',
  'England'
]
----
[
  [
    'India',       'Ireland',
    'Netherlands', 'New Zealand',
    'Pakistan',    'South Africa',
    'Sri Lanka',   'West Indies',
    'Zimbabwe',    'Afghanistan',
    'Australia',   'Bangladesh',
    'England'
  ],
  [
    'India',       'Ireland',
    'Netherlands', 'New Zealand',
    'Pakistan',    'South Africa',
    'Sri Lanka',   'West Indies',
    'Zimbabwe',    'Afghanistan',
    'Australia',   'Bangladesh',
    'England'
  ],
  [
    'India',       'Ireland',
    'Netherlands', 'New Zealand',
    'Pakistan',    'South Africa',
    'Sri Lanka',   'West Indies',
    'Zimbabwe',    'Afghanistan',
    'Australia',   'Bangladesh',
    'England'
  ],
  [
    'India',       'Ireland',
    'Netherlands', 'New Zealand',
    'Pakistan',    'South Africa',
    'Sri Lanka',   'West Indies',
    'Zimbabwe',    'Afghanistan',
    'Australia',   'Bangladesh',
    'England'
  ]
]
```

The "console.log(teams);" works as intended and rotates the array, but the "console.log(shifted);" only shows the last array element pushed 4x as four duplicate elements.

Expected output should be:

```
[
    [
        'Australia',    'Bangladesh',
        'England',      'India',
        'Ireland',      'Netherlands',
        'New Zealand',  'Pakistan',
        'South Africa', 'Sri Lanka',
        'West Indies',  'Zimbabwe',
        'Afghanistan'
    ],
    [
    'Bangladesh',  'England',
        'India',       'Ireland',
        'Netherlands', 'New Zealand',
        'Pakistan',    'South Africa',
        'Sri Lanka',   'West Indies',
        'Zimbabwe',    'Afghanistan',
        'Australia'
    ],
    [
    'England',      'India',
        'Ireland',      'Netherlands',
        'New Zealand',  'Pakistan',
        'South Africa', 'Sri Lanka',
        'West Indies',  'Zimbabwe',
        'Afghanistan',  'Australia',
        'Bangladesh'
    ],
    [
    'India',       'Ireland',
        'Netherlands', 'New Zealand',
        'Pakistan',    'South Africa',
        'Sri Lanka',   'West Indies',
        'Zimbabwe',    'Afghanistan',
        'Australia',   'Bangladesh',
        'England'
    ],
]
```

Logically that should work but here it does not...

Comment: I also don't understand why this could be happening... but you can fix it by doing `shifted.push(...teams);`

Comment: that sadly outputs one long array with the countries repeated like ['A','B', ... 'A', 'B', ... ]

Comment: Also just using ```arrayRotate(teams)``` instead of ```teams = arrayRotate(teams)``` still modifies the teams varible

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo, I wanted to actually write, `shifted.push([...teams]);`, but wrote the otherwise (notice the square brackets)

Comment: That actually worked! thank you!

Still not sure why "teams" was not returning the new array from that function and just directly modifying teams

Comment: @Azotorp, it modifies the teams variable because you pass the link to array not actual values if you don't won't to modify it which will be better just pass argument like this `arrayRotate([...teams])

Answer (score 0):

So thank you to @vrintle and @Alopwer
So i guess now I know that:

```
let array1 = [1,2,3];
let array2 = array1;
let array3 = [...array1];
array1.push(4);
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
console.log(array3);

/* Output:
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] // array1
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] // array2
[ 1, 2, 3 ]    // array3
*/
```

I thought this only applied to objects, but i guess arrays are "objects"